# Writing JPA query from a Native Query

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1, nativequery

I want to write a JPA query from a native query. The Native query is as follows:

```
select alias.fname 
from (select name, fname, lname from student) alias 
where student_id='1';
```

I am unable to create a JPA query from this, any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you replace the query with just `select fname from student where student_id='1'`?

Comment: Just in case there is some particular point, what runtime environmet are you running?  JDK?  Web app server? etc...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [JPQL docs](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_subqueries) and [Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-subqueries), subquery in the `WHERE` clause is not supported. You are left with the options of either:

1. Simplifying your query to just `select fname from student where student_id='1'` (which I assume isn't your real query).
2. Converting your query to use `JOIN`s if possible, or
3. Executing the native query using the [JPA EntityManager.createNativeQuery()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery(java.lang.String)) method. (Least preferred unless you really can't simplify your query.)

Comment: No, actually this is not my actual query, my query is a very complex one. I am getting line exception here, so this is just the sample query and not the original one.